# Combinations without repetition with specific number

Tags: c#, linq, optimization, combinations

I would like to find all ten element combinations without repetitions in such a way that, for example, if we have an array `[0,1,2,3,4]` and I want to find all three-element combinations without repetitions containing the number `0` I get the following result: `0,1,2; 0,1,3; 0,1,4; 0,2,3; 0,2,4; 0,4,3;`

The search method should be fast - finding all combinations and then filtering is too long and for example searching for combinations for k = 10 n = 64 gives `151473214816` combinations and generates an out-of-memory exception (16GB RAM, i7 7600U)

This method takes too long.

To search all combinations for example when `k = 2` or `k = 3` I use the following method:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetKCombs<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, int length) where T : IComparable
{
    if (length == 1)
    {
        return list.Select(t => new T[] { t });
    }
    else
    {
        return GetKCombs(list, length - 1).SelectMany(t => list.Where(o => o.CompareTo(t.Last()) > 0), (t1, t2) => t1.Concat(new T[] { t2 }));
    }
}
```

How should I modify this method to select only combinations that contain a specific number or how should it look new?

Probably the method should not search for all possible combinations, and then filter them only to recreate themselves (recursively?) only those with a specific number but I have no idea how to write such a method or modify the existing one.

Can someone help me solve this problem?

Comment: I would take the set without the selected element/elements (in your case `[0,1,2,3,4]` except `[0]` = `[1,2,3,4]`) and return the same x selected element/s (`[0]`) plus all the N-x combination of the above defined set (`[1,2,3,4]`): at this point it's all standard

Comment: Let's suppose you could process 1 million of those 151,473,214,816 combinations per second (which I think is pretty unlikely) - then it will take nearly two days to process them all. This doesn't seem very practical...

Comment: "_finding all combinations and then filtering is too long_" in fact you have to do the opposite but the filtering must be relevant enough to reduce the remaining combination to a reasonable number

Comment: Easy...use the [Combinatorics](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26050/Permutations-Combinations-and-Variations-using-C-G) project.

Answer (score 1):

I use this method:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Combinations<T>(this IEnumerable<T> elements, int k)
{
    return k == 0 ? new[] { new T[0] } :
      elements.SelectMany((e, i) =>
        elements.Skip(i + 1).Combinations(k - 1).Select(c => (new[] { e }).Concat(c)));
}
```

This would return only combinations with specific instance:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Combinations<T>(this IEnumerable<T> elements, int k, T instance) 
{
    if( k == 0 || !elements.Contains(instance)) return new[] { new T[0] };
    return elements.Where(x => !Equals(x, instance)).Combinations(k - 1).Select(c => (new[] {instance}).Concat(c));
}
```

The idea is simple: get all combinations (k-1 elements) from list without your instance and add instance to result.

I have never checked performance of it. You could give it a try if you want and share your results. Although number of combinations should be the same and I would not expect any big difference in these methods.

Comment: Your method returns all k-elements combinations but i need method which returns all k-elemets combinations Where one of the components of combination will be for example number 10.

Your method i think is faster than my, but not resolve my problem :(

Comment: I have added second method that should do what you need.